# Changing map address with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this code, when user clicks on the div, the map on the changes the position with the updated addresss:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
          <div class="dir">
          <h3 class="title">Shopping abasto</h3>
          <p>tel: 4676-4565</p>
          <p>Avenida Marota</p>
          <div id="map" data-maps="Av. Aconquija 600, Paseo Heller, Yerba Buena, Tucuman"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" id="dir"></span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="dir">
          <h3 class="title">Shopping abasto</h3>
          <p>tel: 4676-4565</p>
          <p>Avenida Marota</p>
          <div id="map" data-maps="Juncal 1213, Buenos Aires, Argentina"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="dir">
          <h3 class="title">Shopping abasto</h3>
          <p>tel: 4676-4565</p>
          <p>Avenida Marota</p>
          <div id="map" data-maps="Paseo Pilar, Del Viso, Buenos Aires Province"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="map">
                <iframe width="100%" height="368" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Buenos%20Aires%2C%20Argentina&key=AIzaSyCDg1Dfoxg3cKcOsucYZQnTjpmPjbUqe2M"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col-separador-s"></div>
            <div class="">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x502">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the map to update the position when clicking on any of the divs with the id 'map'.
The problem is that it only works with the first div, here is my script so far:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#map').on('click', function() {
        var maps = jQuery(this).data('maps');
         jQuery('.map iframe').attr('src','https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=' + maps + '&key=AIzaSyCDg1Dfoxg3cKcOsucYZQnTjpmPjbUqe2M');
    });
});
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML; an `id` must be unique within the document; looking at your code just convert the `id` to a `class`; and update the selector from `$('#map')` to `$('.map')`

Comment: +1 although it's not a good practice to use class as an identifier, better rename your ids map1, map2 and map3 and change `$('#map')` to `$('div[id^=map]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element id's must be unique in the DOM for targeting to work as expected. There will not be errors thrown with the rendering of elements with the same ID, however it goes against standard practice, and introduces issues such as you're experiencing here.

Please refer to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/#article-header-id-1) for a more in-depth differentiation between ID and CLASS.

So, to resolve the issue you're experiencing, you should make the following adjustments:

1. Change map id div's from `<div id="map">` to `<div class="map">`
2. Change map class jQuery selector from `jQuery('#map')` to `jQuery('.map')`
3. Change the `iframe` wrapping div to `<div id="map-wrapper">`
4. Change jQuery selector for the iframe to `jQuery('#map-wrapper iframe')`

Comment: Thanks. Very useful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery's selector by id returns one single element, that's why it's working only for your first element.
You need to use classes instead of id's.

Replace with

```
<div class="map" ... >
```

And match by class

```
jQuery('.map')
```